# Angular form input validation class for not typed in

Tags: angular

There are some CSS input validation classes for Angular forms pristine dirty and invalid. I have an input with a minimum length and I don't want an error message showing for this scenario:

1. user selects/focuses an input
2. unfocuses it without typing anything in it
3. re-focuses the input and begins typing, error message shows immediately saying minimum length not met.

The user may focus the input and decide not to enter anything for it and come back to it later, when they do the error message would show as soon as they type something in it.

Comment: i think pristine is what i'm looking for, might delete this question

Comment: Yes, that's what pristine and dirty are for, you can find examples here https://angular.io/guide/forms#track-control-state-and-validity-with-ngmodel

Comment: actually pristine can't really be used to solve the problem for this scenario, i'll keep the question open

Comment: Why not, if I may ask? If the user focuses that's `touched` but still `pristine`, only if the user types something, it will be `dirty`! Seems like fitting the case you listed.

Comment: as soon as the user types it will not be pristine, i've updated the question it should make more sense

Comment: @el_pup_le, you want the error msg to be shown only when the input field `blur`red but not when he starts typing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I played around with this for a bit and I think that you are correct that you can't get this behavior out of the box with what the reactive forms give you. You can, however, make a directive that will bind to a new class which will allow you to set the styling the way you desire.

You create a directive that listens to the `Blur` event on the `FormControl` and when it occurs check to see if the field is invalid. If it is you can set your own class and then base the styles off of this.

Example:

```js
@Directive({
  selector: '[formControl]',
})
export class ValidationStatusDirective {
  isValidated = false;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef){}

  @HostBinding('class.ng-validated') get ngValidated() { return this.isValidated; }
  @HostBinding('class.ng-unvalidated') get ngUnvalidated() { return !this.isValidated; }

  @HostListener('blur') validationStatusChanged(){
    if(!this.isValidated &&
        this.el.nativeElement.classList.contains('ng-invalid') &&
        this.el.nativeElement.value.length > 0){
      this.isValidated = true;
    }
  }
}
```

You then don't have to modify the HTML at all and then just set the styling when the input is both `ng-invalid` and `ng-validated`

For reference:

```html
<input class="form-control"
    [formControl]="name"
    #input
    placeholder="Enter 3 or more characters">
```

Styles:

```css
input.ng-invalid.ng-validated{
    border-color: red;
    background-color: pink;
}
```

## [Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/u3fHLZUE44GAkc6kIz6b?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

I created this short version using angular doc's example that requires minimum length of 8 but doesn't show the error till user starts typing. Check if this is the case you are looking for.

[Code demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/u65xlsBd4OhnrmcR3V6Y?p=preview)

html:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #heroForm="ngForm">
   <div class="form-group">
     <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name"
           minlength="8"
           [(ngModel)]="model.name" name="name"
           #name="ngModel">
    <div [hidden]="name.valid || name.pristine"
         class="alert alert-danger">
      Name should be at least 8 characters
    </div>
  </div>
 <!-- - -->
</form>
```